# Is it possible to retrieve all many to many fields of a model with a single query?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Suppose if I have a model with around 10 ManyToManyFields. Is it possible to query all the fields of the model with a single query? If not, how do I get the fields with the least db queries as possible (I am using django ORM).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    relation_1  = models.ManyToManyField('app1.model_1')
    relation_2  = models.ManyToManyField('app1.model_2')
    relation_3  = models.ManyToManyField('app1.model_3')
    relation_4  = models.ManyToManyField('app1.model_4')
    relation_5  = models.ManyToManyField('app2.model_5')
    relation_6  = models.ManyToManyField('app2.model_6')
    relation_7  = models.ManyToManyField('app3.model_7')
    relation_8  = models.ManyToManyField('app3.model_8')
    relation_9  = models.ManyToManyField('app3.model_9')
    relation_10 =  models.ManyToManyField('app3.model_10')
```

rightnow, `MyModel.objects.all()` seems so expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.prefetch_related(
    'relation_1', 'relation_2', ..., 'relation_10',
)
```

That will use one query for the initial model, and one query for each many to many field (e.g. 11 queries if you prefetch 10 fields).